# Custom annotation in Swagger CodeGen - java

Tags: java-8, swagger, swagger-codegen

I am using `swagger-codegen-maven-plugin` for generating java pojo classes. I need to use a custom annotation for validation. How can I ask code gen to annotate a field with my custom annotation.

Answer (score 1):

Swagger codegen isn't able to do this. I have seen people work around similar problems by adding an `exec-maven-plugin` task to run a script after codegen that adds what you need.